# Maximum size of Map<Id,Id> in Batch start() before reaching limits

Tags: apex, soql, batch, governorlimits, limits

To do some de-duplication (1: no SELECT DISTINCT in SOQL, 2: GROUP BY restricts me to 50 K records) I rely on a Map  in my Batch `start()` method. How many entries can this map have before I reach the heap size limit of 12 MB?

Comment: It depends on data size .Also little curious as to why you need map in start method..Have jus query in start and in execute method data will be chunked as per batch size ..

Comment: What do you mean by data size? Its a map<Id, Id>.

Comment: how are you forming map?I assume its query.If its just map<id,id> till 50k heap wont hit from my past experience

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum value would be 50,000 rows if you're using an iterator, so that's not practical. Instead, consider using a "used ID set" to filter duplicates. This will give you an upper limit of about 500,000 ID values. Or, sort by ID values in the query, then you only need to remember the most recent set of ID values.

```
global class Processor implements Database.Stateful, Database.Batchable<sobject> {
    set<id> lastbatch = new set<id>();
    global database.querylocator start(database.batchablecontext bc) {
        return database.getquerylocator([select id,accountid from contact order by accountid asc]);
    }
    global void execute(database.batchablecontext bc, contact[] records) {
        set<id> thisbatch = new set<id>(),
                newitems = new set<id>();
        for(contact record:records) {
            thisbatch.add(record.accountid);
        }
        newitems.addall(thisbatch);
        newitems.removeall(lastbatch);
        if(!newitems.isempty()) {
            // do something here
        }
        lastbatch = thisbatch;
    }
    global void finish(database.batchablecontext bc) {

    }
}
```

Comment: How did you calculate this? Or is it experience?

Comment: The 50k is in the Batch Apex docs. The 500k is based on approximate memory usage for ID values in a set. The code I shared has a limit of 50m records, also mentioned in the docs.